# Is it possible to drag-snap a point of a shape being edited by the drawing manager to another shape's point location?

Tags: azure-maps

I'd like a user to be able to draw a polygon using the Azure Maps Drawing Manager and have the ability to move a point of the polygon to near one of another polygon's points and have the dragged point snap to the same location such that the resulting 2 points would be the same.

I know there is snap capability with a grid but don't see a sample for this behaviour?

The ultimate goal is to prevent polygon overlaps, assuming the intersecting shared line of adjoining shapes is excluded from determination of which polygon a point resides within.

I can allow a user to manually draw and get as close as possible of course, and provide some assertion to confirm no polygons overlap but would additionally like a nice snap-to-point experience if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can find hundreds of samples for Azure Maps here: https://samples.azuremaps.com/

As you noted, the snapping grid is likely the best place to start in your scenario. Here are some specific samples of this:

https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=use-a-snapping-grid

https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=snap-grid-options

The following sample is an example of a custom snapping scenario where the routing service is used to snap a drawn line to a route (the route part can be swapped out for custom logic): https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=snap-drawn-line-to-roads

Comment: I'm aware of the samples and have looked there. I don't think the help with specifically locking a single point that was being dragged, i.e. on dragend I would want it to snap to another polygon's position, and still also have the shape in edit mode

Comment: That capability isn't available and the only way to achieve that currently would require accessing undocumented functions or behaviors that would potentially change in the future and break any custom functionality created for this.